# Recursive functions in excel

Tags: excel, recursion, xmldocument

So for a project at work im trying to make a recursive function that does the following:

if the date from cell A2 in Document A is the same as the date from cell B2 from Document B, then check if the string in cell C3 in document A is the same as the string in cell F3 in document B is the same and count how many of those strings there are for a particular date in document B.

I'm not sure how to make the function recursive so that it goes through the whole column with the dates and then recursive through the strings to find the matching string so i can count how many of said string there are in a column that meets those requirements. Thanks!

Edit:

I am not done writing the function as I am currently stumped, but this is what I have so far:

```
=IF(MONTH(M2)&YEAR(M2)=MONTH('G:\QC Lab\Stability\Stability Tracking WorkSheets\2017[Active Stability Tracking Worksheet 2017]Active Stability'!K1)&YEAR('G:\QC Lab\Stability\Stability Tracking WorkSheets\2017[Active Stability Tracking Worksheet 2017]Active Stability'!K1), IF(A2='G:\QC Lab\Stability\Stability Tracking WorkSheets\2017[Active Stability Tracking Worksheet 2017]Active Stability'!
```

So what I noticed is that I do not know how to make it so that it goes through the whole column in the first if statement so I just put K1 because that is the first value that I would be testing (although this would have to change at some point because I need that to go through all of the cells in column K as there will be more added later on in the year and I need the function to check those as its added and not have to update the range everytime new stuff is added). In the second if statement, I don't know how to make it so it checks a certain cell in the row where the first test passed. For example if the first if statement passes and the date is located in cell K10, then check to see if the string in cell C10 is the same as the one in the other document and if so, be able to add a counter or something so that you can count how many of said strings there are under a certain date.

Comment: Add whatever you've been trying and what you are getting wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "recursive"? I suspect that you are not using that word in its usual sense. In Excel rather than VBA the only way to write a recursive function is to use circular references, and trying to do so is almost always a bad idea. VBA supports recursion, though most natural VBA solutions are iterative rather than recursive and stipulating that the solution be recursive seems arbitrary.